# been trying to find this font desperately M and N and E seem the same, any ideas? (I've isolated the letters and alined them at the end to see better)

Tags: fonts, font-identification

been trying to find this font desperately M and N and E seem the same, any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not everything is a font. Looks more like a custom design to me, especially since it's actually molded into the zipper.

Comment: I seriously doubt this is a font. It may have *started* as a font, but it's been manually edited.